# Call javascript interpreter from a script

Tags: java, javascript, scripting, rhino

I've written some scripts in Javascript under Rhino 1.7, one of them starts a minimal http server and accepts JS commands in input.

Now, if I call (from within Rhino):

```
engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

I get the builtin JS engine (from Java 1.6), that is an older version of Rhino, and lacks some functions (like JavaAdapter for multiple interfaces).

How do I get the Rhino Engine instead of that? Do I need ScriptEngineManager.getEngineFactories() or what else?

Comment: Sorry for the redundancy, but: the "engine = ScriptEngineManager()..." is a call in your JS?  Which is being run in Rhino 1.7, but returning the default Java 6 JS script engine instead of Rhino?  Why do you need a new script engine inside of your JS?  Or are you trying to get the current engine / why do you need a reference to the current engine inside of your JS?

Comment: Yes. I need a script to start another interpreter, to avoid using eval().
The first script starts an HTTP server, which serves a single page, with an HTML form in it. The POST method sends a command or file name to the server, and the server-side script executes the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out myself (trial and error). As noted above, Rhino doesn't register an engine factory. You can get the current engine (as a context and a scriptable object):

```
cx = Context.getCurrentContext();
scope = new ImporterTopLevel(cx);
```

With these objects, I can run my scripts or command lines using evalString/evalReader.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is to select a certain version of an script engine which implements "JavaScript". The correct way to do that is to call `ScriptEngineManager.getEngineFactories()` and then check the results of `getLanguageName()` and `getEngineVersion()`.

Answer (score 0):

Before invoking your initial script, why don't you set the engine you're using as a context variable inside the script?  That way, inside the script, you'll have access to the engine that is running it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.
However: changing the java code which runs the javascript engine is what I'm trying to avoid (otherwise I'd implement the whole http-server thing in Java).